# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant BaseController)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I create controller in app/controllers/v1/white_label_api

```
class Api::WhiteLabel::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
end
```

and in other controllers I do

```
class Api::WhiteLabel::V1::CarMakeController < BaseController
```

But it gives an error uninitialized constant BaseController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will be undefined as you have created your controller within module namespace. You can simply get rid of this issue by providing proper namespace for the base.

```
class Api::WhiteLabel::V1::CarMakeController < Api::WhiteLabel::V1::BaseController
```

Or

```
module Api::WhiteLabel::V1
  class CarMakeController < BaseController
```